# How do I use a wildcard to block bots from indexing this?

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt, googlebot

I have the following URL format:

`example.com/page/m6aoeh/embed`

I want to block any bots from indexing any page with the url `/page/*/embed`

I'm assuming there's some way to do wildcard URL block, but just not sure how to do it in this particular case.

Comment: In your example URL, you have `page` (singular) and in your path filter you have `pages` (plural). I'm assuming one of them is a typo. Which one is correct?

Comment: It was a typo. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to indicate to bots that everything under the `/page/` folder should not be indexed by bots, use the [robots.txt exclusion standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html). Create a `/robots.txt` that looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page/
```

If you want bots to index some pages under the `/page` folder but not others, you'll need to add a [`<meta>` tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in the `<head>` to each page you want to exclude.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to do wildcards in the robots.txt file?

Comment: Wildcards are not supported by the [robots.txt exclusion standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html). Some bots might respect non-standard extensions but you can't count it in the general case.